# Custom Drawable not drawn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, ondraw

I am trying to create a custom `Drawable` that converts a square image into a round one. The image is transformed but not drawn.

I can see that if I return the `RoundedBitmapDrawable` in a separate function, it is shown in the `ImageView` but if I expect the overridden function `draw` to do the job, I don'see anything

My class

```
class RoundImage(context: Context?, bitmap: Bitmap): Drawable() {

    private var dr: RoundedBitmapDrawable

    init {
        // give a round shape
        dr = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context!!.resources, bitmap)
        dr.isCircular = true
        dr.cornerRadius = bitmap.width / 2.0f
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        // this draws nothing
        dr.draw(canvas)
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {
        
    }

    override fun setColorFilter(colorFilter: ColorFilter?) {
        
    }

    override fun getOpacity(): Int {
        
    }


    /**
     * This returns a round drawable
     */
    fun getDrawable(): Drawable {
        return dr
    }
}
```

I try to show it with

```
val roundImage = RoundImage(context, bitmap)
myPicture.setImageDrawable(roundImage)
```

Comment: You could just use the Picasso library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need also override `onBoundsChange` method like this:

```
override fun onBoundsChange(bounds: Rect) {
    dr.bounds = bounds
}
```

Alternatively, using `DrawableWrapper` might be a better option.

```
class RoundImage(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap) : DrawableWrapper(null) {

    init {
        // give a round shape
        val dr = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.resources, bitmap)
        dr.isCircular = true
        this.drawable = dr
    }

}
```